# Can I follow a beginner's "Make your own Twitter App" eclipse tutorial using Android Studio instead?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

it is the "Create your own Twitter app" tutorial from Codelearn, what could go wrong? does the xml or java code vary depending on the IDE? please enlighten me on this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is the wrong place to ask. You may be better off asking in a more interactive community, like chat, reddit, or a forum. Your titled question can be answered with Y/N, while a good question leads to an explanation to solve a problem.

Comment: Yes, I know it is very basic, sorry for that, but help me her, yes or no then?

Comment: I cannot help. I am not familiar with your topic, but simply commented for review and in helping you understand the purpose of SO better.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have much trouble using android studio if its just a beginner tutorial. Both are very similar, the java code should be almost identical across IDEs